# What, if anything, replaced the EntityFramework Refresh method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, refresh

I have a product that used an old version of Entity Framework (don't know the version) that I have to update to EF6.  In the older EF there used to be a method on an entity called `Refresh` to update the table contents.  For example:

```
EFDataEntity.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, EFDataEntity.TableOne);
```

to update the EF table `TableOne` so that `EFDataEntity.TableOne` had the latest data from the SQL table.

On EF6 this method no longer exists.  I tried this:

```
EFDataEntity.Entry(EFDataEntity.TableOne).Reload();
```

but it throws exception

> The entity type DbSet`1 is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

How does one refresh the table in EF6?

Comment: Did you pass an _instance_ of an entity?  What is `BEDataEntity.TableOne`?  Based on your naming, `BEDataEntity` looks like a context and `TableOne` seems to be a `DbSet<>`

Comment: Sorry, the correct code should be EFDataEntity.Entry(EFDataEntity.TableOne).Reload();  I fixed it in the original question

Comment: To answer your questions, EFDataEntity is the entity framework object, TableOne is a table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can either dispose your current context and create a new one or if you don't want to do this for some reason you can also do this:  `yourcontext.Entry(yourEntity).Reload()`
[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads)  ||  [Working with DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext)

Comment: Thanks, but I think that refreshes the entire entity, when I just want to refresh a single table.  In any case, I tried that, and I get Exception     "{"The entity type BEEnterpriseEntities is not part of the model for the current context."}  BEEnterpriseEntities is the type of my EF object.